# adding two attributes in a table and then use AS

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I want to use two attributes in one table, and then making them as one by using AS.

the data inside the database :

> user_lastname : Yu 
>   user_firstname : Mark

The Query :

```
SELECT  user_lastname + user_firstname AS name
```

Expected output would be :

```
Yu Mark
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

```
SELECT CONCAT(user_lastname, ' ', user_firstname) AS name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CONCAT_WS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)

```
SELECT concat_ws(' ', user_lastname, user_firstname) AS name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a alias name for the fields which you wants by using the keyword AS. Then you can get the single column.